# Why new (SQLite) database file is created with each transaction?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an android application that saves transaction history in database file (sqlite) on the sdcard. Problem is, there are a lot of records and after a certain number of records have been stored or at a certain size, the application creates another similar database file to save to.

Can anyone tell me after how many record numbers or what size the database will do this?

```
 select count(*) from users where uname=? pwd=?;
database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_FILE_PATH + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME+i, null);
        createTables();
```

Comment: How do you intend to use the db? - Continuously *adding* to it should work for pretty much of data, probably far more than you should actually store on a mobile.

Answer (score 1):

because of this  `DATABASE_NAME+i` where i is your generated newfile id .

Comment: my question is about database performance, i want to know the max number of records or the max size of database so the performance of the application won't be slow, so is there any static number or size for database for the performance ( SQLite ).

Comment: i have read those number before but it talk about maximum capacity and i use phone not pc so i want know that after how many number of row performance of the data base be slow in my view should be 4-6 MB but want standard number

Comment: 1.st your performance will be restricted to the cpu speed of your phone. 2. the sd card i/o speed 3. correctness of your queries/architecture/indexes and periodical compacting of your db if there will be too many deletes/updates. If your queries and indexes are right you should not experience any bad issues. It will only be restricted to the i/o speed of your sdcard and the size of the indexes when doing queries. 4-6mb is nothing. Here are the performance tests for sqlite http://www.sqlite.org/speed.html.

Comment: I would say there is no general rule for all phones. Because db performance may vary drastically depending on the phone.